# I cannot get my dropdown to show in my Django Admin Panel

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

Hey I've been doing django projects for some time but I realised I do not really like the style of the admin panel so I decided I would redo it

What seems to not work is that there's a "View Site" and "Change Password" link which I wanted to put in a dropdown to make it cleaner but when I did the dropdown it just shows white like this:

https://gyazo.com/5b6c6f76ce39870cb26f11f83be52221

My code:

```
<div id="header" class = "navbar navbar-collapse fixed-top">
        <div id= "branding">
        {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        {% block usertools %}
        {% if has_permission %}
        <div id = "user-tools" style = "overflow: visible !important;">
        {% block userlinks %}
            <div class = "navbar-nav nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="overflow: visible !important;">
                Dropdown
                </a>
                 <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                     {% if site_url %}
                     <a class="dropdown-item-text" href="{{ site_url }}">{% trans 'Visit Site' %}</a>
                     <a class="dropdown-item-text" href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a>
                     {% endif %}
                     {% if user.has_usable_password %}
                     <a class="dropdown-item-text" href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a>
                     {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
        {% endif %}
        {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
```

And these are the scripts I added to the head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```